# POST XML string to ASP.Net page with Ajax: Error 500 (internal Server error)

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Im sending an XML string with Ajax to a ASP.net page which is meant to process the XML. I have tested sending a testing string with just: "Test" in it and it worked fine. I get an issue when I send my XML string, Jquery just then returns a 500 (internal Server error).
Heres my code:

```
  var xmlString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlData);
    console.log(xmlString); // This works fine.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx",
        dataType:"text/xml", // I have tried it both with and without dataType
        data: {xml: xmlString}, // If I set the xmlString var to something like "test" it works fine.
        success: function (reply) {
            console.log("Complete!");
            console.log(reply);
        },
    });
```

Heres the error:

```
POST http://localhost:49469/WebForm1.aspx 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The page has nothing on it, its meant to just take the POST data (which it does fine, so long as its not an XML string) and go from there. Like said, it works fine so long as its not XML thats being POSTed.

As requested, heres the code to my WebForm1.aspx:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
        var value = "";

        for (int i = -0; i < keys.Length; i++){
            value = Request.Form[keys[i]];
            Response.Write(value);
        }

    }
```

Doesnt do much at the moment because I want to test it.

Comment: Debugging the code behind of `WebForm1` when making the ajax request that errors may help shed some light on this.

Comment: If you add a break point (F9 in Visual Studio) and run with the debugger attached (F5) and run the ajax method you should be able to see exactly which part of your code is causing the error along with a more descriptive error message.